# How to draw Y-axis grid in core-plot?

Tags: iphone, core-plot

How to draw X-axis grid, ie draw horizontal line against y=axis value?
please help me out?

sri

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to set the `majorGridLineStyle` and/or `minorGridLineStyle` properties on your axes. See CPTestApp in the examples folder for some sample code.

Comment: What will be the value of majorGridLineStyle??

Comment: Using `[CPTLineStyle lineStyle]` will give a thin black line. You can also create a `CPTMutableLineStyle` and modify the style properties including the color, width, line join, and dash pattern to customize the look.